# Can't import local module inside script, like I do in Django shell

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitterstream.py", line 3, in <module>
from tweemo.models import TwitterStream
ImportError: No module named tweemo.models
```

Background:

In Django I have a simple model which looks like so:

```
from django.db import models

class TwitterStream(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField()
```

From inside the Django shell I can do the following without problems

```
>>> from tweemo.models import TwitterStream
>>> tweet = TwitterStream.objects.create(text = 'hello again')
>>> tweet.text
'hello again'
```

Because this worked in the django shell, I thought I could insert this line:

```
>>> from tweemo.models import TwitterStream
```

into any regular python script and, for example, insert the data into the TwitterStream Model (and thus my into my Mondo Database) form within the script.

Basically, I have a script which does print out the twitter live stream onto the command line. Itried to modify it by including this

```
 >>> from tweemo.models import TwitterStream
```

and changing this:

```
for line in response:
    print response
```

into this:

```
for line in response:
    tweet = str(tweet) + str(" ") + str(count) 
    tweet = TwitterStream.objects.create(text = line.strip())
    count += 1
```

FYI: My models.py containing the TwitterStream class is inside my app 'tweemo' which is inside a project, also called 'twitter'. The python script I want to send the live stream into mymongo DB with, is in the same folder as the models.py file -the tweemo app folder.

[image]

I'm new to Django/Mongo so Imight be way off here..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Python will automatically check for modules in the same directory as the input script, so you can just write

```
from models import TwitterStream
```

This behaviour is different when you are in the django shell, as django appends the project root path to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), which Python also uses when [searching for modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Answer (score 0):

if importing of model works via django shell it has to work via py files within project folder.
My only guess would be to delete pyc file in project folder and test.If not, @dannymilsom solution will come in handy :)